# Matlab "evaluate selection" slows down code

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab R2017b and I'm running a very simple snippet:

```
tic
t(1) = toc;
t(2) = toc;
t(3) = toc;
t(4) = toc;
t(5) = toc;
t(6) = toc;
t(7) = toc;

t = t - [0 t(1:end-1)];
```

If I run it with Run option in Editor menu of Matlab IDE the resulting `t` has values around `10e-5` seconds (Figure below).
[image: Run with Run option]

If I run the very same script with Evaluate Selection (select the code, right click and then Evaluate Selection) the values are around `10e-3` seconds (Figure below).
[image: Run with Evaluate Selection option]

Anyone knows the reason of this heavy slow down?
I tried with 3 different laptops (Linux and Windows OS) but nothing changed.

Comment: Thats a debugging tool, not to use for timing. Its reasonable to have it take longer. Probably because the JIT doesn't apply to the code you right click and run.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. Matlab documented this in some place?

Comment: I doubt it is documented.

Comment: I had to try, thank you again!

Comment: Try not to rely too much on timing at this range of intervals. Also note that you should probably clear all your variables between both tests. But I also believe the reason is undocumented.